# Find substring using starting and ending word in a string and substrings indexes in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to find a substring in a string if i give starting and ending tags/words to function and returns me substring with its starting and ending index in java script

Comment: possible, but what have you tried?

Comment: i am not sure what function should i use for that ,
var string = "[start] hello [/start] helo how are you";
var substring = myfunction(string,'[start]',['end']);

i would like to implement that kind of function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

some function like this

```
function extractword(str, start, end){
  var startindex = str.indexOf(start);
  var endindex = str.indexOf(end, startindex);
  if (startindex !=-1 && endindex !=-1 &&  endindex  > startindex )
    return str.substring(startindex , endindex )
}
```

or can use some regex if you know

Answer (score 2):

You would like to use this code:

```
function extractText(strToParse, strStart, strFinish){
  return strToParse.match(strStart + "(.*?)" + strFinish)[1];
}

extractText("first second third", "first", "third");​
```

Here is simple  [example](http://jsfiddle.net/qFTMp/2/)

Answer (score -1):

To find index of a substring in a string you should use the [indexof method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp).

To extract a substring us the [substring method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp).

If after reading the documentation for the methods you try them out and still have questions, please post your code so we can help further.